# What makes a fisherman's hat so popular among outdoorsmen?

Tags: clothing

Lately I've recognized the huge amount of fisherman's hats on a 3D archery tournament. Also, I see them a lot while hiking.
[image: Fisherman's hat]

I can't really figure out what makes them superior above a common hat
[image: Common hat]
or cap
[image: Cap with neck protection].
Has somebody an explanation why it is not just popular among fishermen (why it is popular among fishermen is also interesting of course), but all kinds of outdoor activity?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few benefits why this has evolved as a good choice for fishermen. These benefits apply to other outdoor activities also! That's why the hat is popular among all kinds of outdoorsmen. However, I'll explain the advantages based on fishing but it's mostly common sense to figure out similar circumstances for other activities.

First of all, fishing often means to be a lot in the bright sun (on a boat, near the river with no trees etc.). That's why a good fisherman hat provides a UV protection of 40+.

> Product features
>
> - Material: 100% organic cotton
> - Brim: approx. 5.3 cm
> - Height of crown: approx. 8.5 cm
> - **UV protection 40+**

[From random example product](http://www.hatshopping.com/s01.php?shopid=s01&cur=eur&sp=en&ag=1&pp=suche&suchstr=70850&I1=%A0%A0SEARCH)

They are also waterproof for nearly the same reason. If it starts to rain, everything is fine (at least around your head) :). Also they can be used to scoop and hold water (practical things like bucket-replacement but also to cool yourself down or drink) then. Additionally they are of course breathable and stay on your head while it's windy (they sit tighter than a hunting hat for example). This is important since you often investigate strong winds while fishing (open water). For colder temperatures, there are even ones with fleece.

> Die meisten dieser Hüte sind ein guter Schutz vor Regen, da sie nahezu
>   wasserdicht sind. Es gibt auch Anglerhüte, die einen sehr hohen
>   Lichtschutzfaktor und vor Sonnenbrand und Sonnenstich schützen. Für
>   sehr kalte Regionen oder Winterangler kann man auch sehr warme
>   Anglerhüte bekommen, die beispielsweise aus Fleece hergestellt werden.
>   Die Materialien für Anglerhüte sind generell atmungsaktiv.

Source: [Anglerhut von www.anglerhut.com](http://www.anglerhut.com)

Google Translate:

Most of these hats are a good protection against rain, because they are virtually waterproof. There are also fishing hats that protect a very high sun protection factor and against sunburn and sunstroke. For very cold regions or winter anglers can also get very warm Angler hats, which are made for example of fleece. The materials for fishermen hats are generally breathable.

Answer (score 6):

Fisherman hats are good at shading the face and neck.  They typically have a downward sloping 360 degree brim.

[image]

I doubt you are seeing open water strap it down type hats on the archery range.  It is more a [bucket hat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_hat).  It is used for a variety of  activities.  Nike [Nike sells one as a golf cap](http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pd/bucket-golf-hat/pid-10990886/pgid-11161208).  Here is one sold as an [archery hat](http://www.lancasterarchery.com/lancaster-archery-supply-flex-fit-bucket-hat.html).  [Under armor](https://www.underarmour.com/en-us/mens-ua-airvent-bucket-hat/pid1273240-001) specifically mentions skin protection.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to TGO. Could you please elaborate the answer a bit, as it stands it is more a comment and isn't really giving lots of information.

Comment: That's not really a unique selling point. In fact, there are dozens of hat styles which have a 360 degree brim.

Comment: @OddDeer  Yes, hats are going to have a lot of commonalities.  They all cover your head.  You specifically asked what makes them superior above a common hat or cap.  That is a specific difference.  There are also many types of fisherman hats.

Comment: @Paparazzi Sill, a common hat has also the 360 degree brim. A cap may also cover neck and face (these neckbeard desert caps). There has to be something really unique to these caps. Why would it have been evolved to a hat designed specifically for fishermen than? They just could have worn a hat. I assume (!) that it's the wind resistance. When they were on stormy sea or sitting near it, the hat just didn't fall off.

Comment: @OddDeer A common hat or cap has 360?  Has to be something really unique?   It is specially designed for fishermen?  I see them sold at golf and tennis shops and they carry no fishing gear.  You have a lot of assumptions and rules.  Comments are not for discussion.

Comment: @Paparazzi FYI: this community is not as grumpy as SO :) I just wanted to say that there is a reason that a fisherman hat is called a "fisherman" hat - and we are searching for it.

Comment: @OddDeer So now the question is "there is a reason that a fisherman hat is called a fisherman hat - and we are searching for it"?   I only have a limited sample on the site but I find you to be grumpy.    I would say a fisherman hat is called a fisherman for the same reason a baseball cap is called a baseball cap.   I still contend you are seeing sports style bucket hats on the archery range.  Why don't you post some pictures of the hats you see?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/43448/discussion-between-odddeer-and-paparazzi).

Answer (score 5):

I think one of the reasons for the popularity of fishermen hat types is that they are easily r**olled up/folded** and put away in a pocket. The same is not possible with most traditional (felt) hats, and even if you get a folding/rolling felt that they'll still be a lot heavier and bulkier.

Fisherman hats are also **fairly light**, made from cotton (or nowadays synthetics) - an other advantage over heavier traditional felt hats.

Comment: I really like your point about the roll-up ability. Never thought about that - great one!

Answer (score 3):

Surprisingly, the simplest but in my eyes most important feature of fishermen hats was overlooked when it comes to archery:

**They have a brim that isn't stiff, and will bend/fold away when you draw the bow string close to your face.**

In classic recurve or compound archery the bowman draws the string of the bow towards his face and 'anchors' there, i.e. he touches his face with the string (commonly the tip of the nose) or with the hand holding the string/trigger (or both).
This helps to keep a consistent, even form between different shots, wich is important as a little difference in draw length and body position will have a huge impact on your accuracy.

The fishermans hat is used because as you draw the string close, it would interfere with other hats that come with a stiffer brim, such as a baseball cap or a felt hat / stetson.

Back in my recurve archery days the fisherman hats were commonly used by many archers at the range. What I also saw were some personal mods where people took baseball camps and cut int slots into the brim, such that the bow string would never touch the hat when drawn close.